# Groupby column value and keep row based on another column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame, `df`, that has a range of values such as:

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | AB001 |
| 02 | AB002 |
| 02 | BC123 |
| 02 | CD576 |
| 03 | AB444 |
| 03 | CD332 |
| 04 | BC434 |
| 04 | CD894 |

I want to remove all duplicates in the `ID` column and keep the row that has a certain value in `Code`. Let's suppose that if the `Code` that starts with BC is available, I want to keep that row. Otherwise, I want to take the first row with the `ID`. My desired output would look like:

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | AB001 |
| 02 | BC123 |
| 03 | AB444 |
| 04 | BC434 |

I want to do something like:

```
# 'x' denotes a list of rows per unique ID
def keep_row(x):
    # determine if 'BC' is even an available Code
    if any([True for row in x if row['Code'].startswith('BC') else False]):
        return the row that has Code that starts with BC
    else:
        # return the first row with the unique ID if there is no Code that begins with BC
        return x[0]

 
df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: keep_row(x))
```

I'd appreciate any help - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort your dataframe by `ID` and boolean value (`False` when Code starts with `"BC"`), then `.groupby()` and take first item:

```
df["tmp"] = ~df.Code.str.startswith("BC")
df = df.sort_values(by=["ID", "tmp"])
print(df.groupby("ID", as_index=False)["Code"].first())
```

Prints:

```
   ID   Code
0   1  AB001
1   2  BC123
2   3  AB444
3   4  BC434
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked well and was very straightforward